# Display video when marker detection occurs in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, augmented-reality

I am working on augmented reality. I just followed this https://ar.qualcomm.at/sdk/ios link and downloaded vuforia-videoplayback-ios-1-0-2.zip.

When I build it in xcode 4.2 an error occours that states:

> Lexical or preprocessor issue 'QCAR/Tool.h' file not found

I just can't solve it. I will be grateful if anyone can point to any more information that could help me out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this in the official forums, maybe it contains valuable info:

https://ar.qualcomm.at/content/ios-getting-started-tutorial

There is a link to a question on SO:

[Adding system header search path to Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428216/adding-system-header-search-path-to-xcode)

That seemed to help someone with a similar problem:

https://ar.qualcomm.at/content/problems-linking-qcar-files

Comment: Thanks for ur reply RaynCGN.  
I added "${SRCROOT}" without recursive as HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS parameter in build settings on project info. I have also tried build/include as HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS parameter. But no solution.

By the way, when i downloaded the source code..i found a folder named ARCommon and a library libQCAR.a colored red by xcode. I have added both of them from vuforia SDK into my code and then at the time of clean no error occours. But when i build it same error occours all the time. I just cann't understand where the problem was? 

Again Thanx for reply....

Comment: That is strange, maybe you could ask at the official forums? I for myself are no expert at this, I have just googled it, so I'm very sorry I have no further advice :(

Answer (score 0):

In project Build Settings -> set from Basic to the ALL -> Search Path -> in row Header Search Paths fill correct path to the build

if you have got still problem set chmod -R 0777 {sdk vuforia}/