# How to import <UI7Kit/UI7Kit.h> to Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I used cocoapods to install some dependencies related with UI7Kit to my xcode project. After using "pod install", Pod created a xcode workspace for me, but the problem is: I cannot import the  to main.m file. (ref to the guideline here https://github.com/youknowone/UI7Kit)

When using "pod install", the Terminal had some logs like this:

**[!] The target `MyProjectTarget [Debug]` overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
    - Use the`$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.**

How to fix it? Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I wish I found this question earlier.

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3428303/1786241

And change it to $(inherited)