# Installed freetype through homebrew, can't seem to include headers correctly

Tags: c++, freetype

On my xcode project, I added the dylib of freetype to the project Link Binary phase.

I ensure `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` are in search paths in the build settings.

I then include:

```
#include <freetype2/ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
```

But i get an error that `freetype.h` was not found. Any ideas? I tried including `<freetype2/freetype.h>` directly, but that leads to more compile problems with include paths in other freetype files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the demo programs in "freetype2-demos", I see:

```
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
```

Also, I think you need your compiler command-line to include `-I (path to freetype includes)`.

For example...

```
g++ -I (...)/freetype2 myfile.cpp
```

[Here are the instructions](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html#section-1).  The suggestion there is to compile with something like...

```
g++ $(freetype-config --cflags) myfile.cpp
```

...which, if you system is configured correctly, will incorporate the `-I` option that I previously mentioned.

Comment: Don't think you're wrong, but I solved it another way. Libraries i've been using so far like Glew have worked by adding the dylib file to the project, and ensuring `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` is in the search path. Freetype however, i had to add the folder directly for the headers: `/usr/local/include/freetype2`. Then i was able to use the include statement as you have it. No other compiler options changed.

Comment: @agmcleod: Adding the include folder `/usr/local/include/freetype2` to the list of headers is probably how you tell xcode to use the `-I` option as I described.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3428303/86967).