# Is there a way in Xcode 11 to add global header search paths?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, path

Absolute Xcode newbie here.
Is there a way to add header search paths globally (ie. non-project specific), or is adding them in each project's Build Settings the only way?
It feels kind of silly to have to add the same paths to every project I make, so you'd think there is a way to add them globally, but I just can't find it.
(I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428216/adding-system-header-search-path-to-xcode), but the 'Preferences->Locations->"Source Trees" in Xcode's preference' mentioned does not seem to exist anymore)